# Python/Pandas: 'orient' = 'index' argument in read_json changes column datatype

Tags: python, json, pandas

I recently faced a strange behavior using pandas' "read_json" method. I have a list of JSON files in a directory `mypath` which I want to read with pandas, append and get a final data set. I did this using a loop and append data as follows:

```
from os.path import join
import pandas as pd
from os import listdir

GroundTruthFiles=[file for file in listdir(mypath) if file.endswith(".json")]
dfGroundTruth=pd.read_json(join(mypath,GroundTruthFiles[0]),orient="index")

for file in GroundTruthFiles[1:]:
    nextfile=pd.read_json(join(mypath,file),orient="index")
    dfGroundTruth=dfGroundTruth.append(nextfile)
```

The JSON files do all have the same data formats and contain a variable of interest ('driving_time') which has a `float` format. When I create the initial dataframe, the column 'driving_time' keeps its `float` format. However, when I iterate over the other files, the data type is converted into a `datetime64[ns]` format. The final dataframe has an `object`format for my variable 'driving time'

I tried using the read_json built-in option `orient`

```
 for .... :
    pd.read_json(..., dtype = {'driving_time : float})
```

but this did not solve my issue.

I also iterated the files as follows:

```
 for .... :
    nextfile=pd.read_json(join(mypath,file)).T
```

which works for the variable itself but modifies the data types of all other (which I want to avoid).

Is there any explication for this strange behavior? And an elegant solution to my problem?

Comment: Can you provide a runnable, self-contained example including data that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Sorry for my late response: Unfortunately, it is sensitive data. I managed to integrate a workaround due to strict deadlines, but the error rests however mysterious

Comment: I understand about the sensitive data. Would you be able to manually create some completely fake data that still reproduces the issue? Without that, it's a lot harder to investigate.